# Local Azure-Domain-Joined-Server (ADS) can't SSO

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-domain-services

Is it Possible to get SSO working on a DomainJoined Server? (ADS)

A Local Terminal Server (MS Server 2016) is connected via VirtualVPN to the Azure-Active-Directory-Service. An Office Subscription is Active as well as a Azure P1 License.

On the Server there is an Office 365 MSO (16.0.11425.20242) installed.

The result for dsregcm /status is:

+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device State                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+

```
    AzureAdJoined : NO
 EnterpriseJoined : NO
     DomainJoined : YES
       DomainName : DOMAINES-KILGER
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User State                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
           NgcSet : NO
  WorkplaceJoined : NO
    WamDefaultSet : NO
       AzureAdPrt : NO
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ngc Prerequisite Check                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
    IsUserAzureAD : NO
    PolicyEnabled : NO
   DeviceEligible : YES
```

SessionIsNotRemote : NO
     X509CertRequired : NO
         PreReqResult : WillNotProvision

Inter Internet SecuritySettings that are needed by Microsoft are set:

-IntranetZones: aadg.window.net.nsatc.net
-IntranetZones: autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com
-Allow updates to status bar via script

At this point the SSO does not work at all. 
Not in the iexplore or in the login to a Office-Product when it is startet to check for a License